# C# graphics draws behind Panel

Tags: c#, winforms

Im in winforms and trying to make a tileengine in it for school reasons. I have a trouble with drawing the tileset in the Panel. It's instead drawing in the top left of the Form and behind the Panel.

This is the code:

```
private void gfxPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            using (Bitmap sourceBmp = new Bitmap("../../assets/art/Tileset5.png"))
            {
                Size s = new Size(level.TileWidth, level.TileHeight);
                Rectangle destRect = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, s);

                for (int row = 0; row <= level.MapHeight; row++)
                    for (int col = 0; col < level.MapWidth; col++)
                    {
                        PictureBox p = new PictureBox();
                        p.Size = s;
                        Point loc = new Point(level.TileWidth * col, level.TileHeight * row);
                        Rectangle srcRect = new Rectangle(loc, s);
                        Bitmap tile = new Bitmap(level.TileWidth, level.TileHeight);
                        Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(tile);
                        G.DrawImage(sourceBmp, destRect, srcRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                        p.Image = tile;
                        p.Location = loc;
                        this.Controls.Add(p);
                    }
            }
        }
```

Whats going on here and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: In the Paint event you should Paint: Use e.Graphics.DrawImage(yourBitmap, ..) Don't add pictureBoxes unless you really mean it!

Comment: hi, thank you! Will do! What do you mean really mean it? Can I only draw one then?

Comment: You can draw as many tiles onto the Panel as you want. But adding Controls is something completely different: One is coloring a few pixels the other creates a lot of Window-like objects. These have many options and are powerful if you need that but they are also expensive. You need to decide what you want!

Comment: Huh... What would you recommend to do instead?

Comment: It depends what you want to do with the tiles.. If they are used as object that move around, interact with the user etc then they should be controls. If all they do is to make up an image they should simply be painted..

Comment: Yeah, they're just going to be painted and nothing more really. Bitmaps then

Comment: In that case I would certainly not create any Controls to display them. Drawing the bitmaps is no more work..I can post an answer if you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding the picture boxes to the form (`this`). Add them to the panel instead:

```
gfxPanel.Controls.Add(p);
```

Note: You are adding the controls in the paint event, which means that you will be adding multiple sets of the same control. The paint even is called whenever the control needs to be redrawn on the screen. You should only add the controls once, perhaps in the form load event. If you want to use the paint event you should use the graphics object that is send in the event arguments to draw directly on the screen, not add controls that contain what you want to draw.

Comment: Thank you! The note was ery helpful and appreciated aswell!

Answer (score 1):

If you really just want to draw the tiles without interaction you can change the `Paint` event like this:

```
private void  gfxPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    using (Bitmap sourceBmp = new Bitmap("../../assets/art/Tileset5.png"))
    {
        Size s = new Size(levelTile.Width, levelTile.Height);

        for (int row = 0; row <= levelMap.Height; row++)
            for (int col = 0; col < levelMap.Width; col++)
            {
                Rectangle destRect =  new Rectangle(
                         col * levelTile.Width, row * levelTile.Height, 
                         levelTile.Width, levelTile.Height);
                Point loc = new Point(levelTile.Width * col, levelTile.Height * row);
                Rectangle srcRect = new Rectangle(loc, s);
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(sourceBmp, destRect, srcRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            }
    }

}
```

Note that I didn't fully rewrite the code. If the tiles are meant to be drawn in the same order and size as they appear in the TileSet the whole TileSet could be drawn directly..

Comment: +1 thank you! this is certainly what I'm trying to do. I don't want to draw them in the same order, but that's pretty simple to fix later, I just needed to understand this and what I should do to draw.